# AngularJS - Populating HTML Drop-Down with JSON from REST API (without $scope)

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

A lot of solutions on Stack Overflow in relation to populating drop down menus include `$scope`.

My second drop-down depends on the value of my first drop-down therefore I use `ng-change`on the first HTML `select` to parameter pass the model ID into the 2nd drop-down's function.

**1st Drop-Down HTML and Angular JS:**

```
<select data-ng-controller="addAssetController as addAssetCtrl" id="functionalOrg" data-ng-model="addAssetFormCtrl.functionalOrg.id" ng-change="addAssetCtrl.getLocations(addAssetFormCtrl.functionalOrg.id)">

    <option data-ng-repeat="functionalOrg in addAssetCtrl.functionalOrgs | orderBy:'id' track by $index" value="{{functionalOrg.id}}">
        {{functionalOrg.id}} - {{functionalOrg.account}}
    </option>

</select>
```

Hence `ng-change`:

```
ng-change="addAssetCtrl.getLocations(addAssetFormCtrl.functionalOrg.id)"
```

-

```
var vm = this;

functionalOrganisationRepository.getFunctionalOrganisation().then(function (results) {
    vm.functionalOrgs = results;
}, function (error) {
    vm.error = true;
    vm.errorMessage = error;
});
```

**The 2nd Drop-Down HTML and Angular:**

```
<select data-ng-controller="addAssetController as addAssetCtrl" id="location" data-ng-model="addAssetFormCtrl.location.id">

    <option data-ng-repeat="location in addAssetCtrl.locations | orderBy:'id' track by $index" value="{{location.id}}">
        {{location.id}} - {{location.address6}}
    </option>

</select>
```

-

```
vm.getLocations = function(id) {

    console.log("Functional org ID:" + id);

        locationRepository.getLocation(id).then(function (results) {
            vm.locations = results;
        }, function (error) {
            vm.error = true;
            vm.errorMessage = error;
        });
}
```

Assuming my service layer is fine and brings back a JSON object with everything I require, what could the problem be? The `vm.getLocations` function is definitely getting called because my console log is being printed. The service layer is also fine because a JSON object to being logged to my command prompt.

My question is how do I populate my second drop-down from whatever JSON is returned by `getLocations`? Please hence I do not want to make use of `$scope` in Angular.

Comment: please create a plunker and provide

Comment: the method locationRepository.getLocation(id) retrieves a list?

Comment: The "ng-controller" attribute is repeated on each select. Put the attribute only one time on a parent element!

Comment: @manzapanza post that as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ng-controller" attribute is repeated on each select. Put the attribute only one time on a parent element!

```
<div data-ng-controller="addAssetController as addAssetCtrl">

<!-- Drop Down 1 and 2 here -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont share scope you can't do what you want to do.  Meaning if you dont have a parent vm or pass something to your directive `=` you can't tell what is selected.

Pull up your controller a level and share it among selected or you are going to have to either watch a shared variable in a service, or rely on `$on` & `$broadcast` to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that this is because they have different scopes and different controllers.

Assuming that the actual HTML looks like the following:

```
<select data-ng-controller="addAssetController as addAssetCtrl" id="location" data-ng-model="addAssetFormCtrl.location.id">

    <option data-ng-repeat="location in addAssetCtrl.locations | orderBy:'id' track by $index" value="{{location.id}}">
        {{location.id}} - {{location.address6}}
    </option>

</select>

<select data-ng-controller="addAssetController as addAssetCtrl" id="functionalOrg" data-ng-model="addAssetFormCtrl.functionalOrg.id" ng-change="addAssetCtrl.getLocations(addAssetFormCtrl.functionalOrg.id)">

    <option data-ng-repeat="functionalOrg in addAssetCtrl.functionalOrgs | orderBy:'id' track by $index" value="{{functionalOrg.id}}">
        {{functionalOrg.id}} - {{functionalOrg.account}}
    </option>

</select>
```

Then, to the best of my knowledge, each select will get a different instance of the controller, each with different scopes. So you've effectively got a controller `addAssetCtrl1` and `addAssetCtrl2`, so setting data on `1` does not set it on `2`.

The solution would be to set the data on a parent controller, or, probably more simply, to do the following:

```
<div data-ng-controller="addAssetController as addAssetCtrl">
    <select id="location" data-ng-model="addAssetFormCtrl.location.id">

        <option data-ng-repeat="location in addAssetCtrl.locations | orderBy:'id' track by $index" value="{{location.id}}">
            {{location.id}} - {{location.address6}}
        </option>

    </select>

    <select id="functionalOrg" data-ng-model="addAssetFormCtrl.functionalOrg.id" ng-change="addAssetCtrl.getLocations(addAssetFormCtrl.functionalOrg.id)">

        <option data-ng-repeat="functionalOrg in addAssetCtrl.functionalOrgs | orderBy:'id' track by $index" value="{{functionalOrg.id}}">
            {{functionalOrg.id}} - {{functionalOrg.account}}
        </option>

    </select>
</div>
```